# A function vanishing in infinity with zero integral is integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Suppose we have a continuous function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ s.t.:

- $f(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $||x|| \rightarrow \infty$;
- $\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}f(x)dx = 0$;

Would that mean that $\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}|f(x)|dx < \infty$? It seems like it can be true by some form of generalization of [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test)
 to integrals. If not, a counterexample would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: On $\mathbb R^1,$ function

$$f(x) =\frac{\sin x}{x} - \frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

satisfies your two conditions, yet

$$\int_{\mathbb R}|f(x)|\,dx = \infty.$$